# Stochastic Differential equation, expectation and variance

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, differential, stochastic-differential-equations

The process is given by
$$dU_t=-\gamma U_t\mathrm{d}t+\sigma\mathrm{d}X_t$$

where $U_0 = u$ and $\gamma, \sigma$ are constants. Can you help me out to solve the equation for $U_t$ and find the expectation and variance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$dU_t + \gamma U_t dt = \sigma X_t$$ which is $$d(e^{\gamma t}U_t) = e^{\gamma t}\sigma dX_t$$
So $$e^{\gamma t}U_t - e^{\gamma 0}U_0 = \int_0^t e^{\gamma s}\sigma dX_s$$
i.e. $$U_t = e^{-\gamma t}U_0 + \int_0^t e^{\gamma (s-t)}\sigma dX_s$$

Can you go from here?