# Expectation and Variance of stochastic equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, expectation

My questions is related to this question: 
[Stochastic Differential equation, expectation and variance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/981509/stochastic-differential-equation-expectation-and-variance/997170#997170)

I.e how do you calculate the variance and expectation of $U_t = e^{-\gamma t}U_0 + \int_0^t e^{\gamma (s-t)}\sigma dX_s$?

Comment: what is $X_t$???

Comment: I guess $dX_t$ is the Brownian motion.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ is a Brownian motion then, as the function inside the stochastic integral is bounded,
the stochastic integral is centered and, if $U_0$ is deterministic:
$$
E(U_t) = e^{-\gamma t} U_0
$$

Then, using the [Ito isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_isometry):
$$
E\left[U_t-E(U_t)\right]^2 =
E\left(
\int_0^t e^{\gamma(s-t) } \sigma dX_s
\right)^2 
= \int _0^t  e^{2\gamma(s-t) } \sigma^2ds
$$

Comment: thanks, thats very interested, can you use this result in calculating the variance (as you do for non stochastic?)

Comment: the variance is the second equation!

Comment: Correct. It uses the definition of variance.

Comment: how did you change the integral from $\partial X_s$ to $\partial s$ and if possible can you please give the proof for the expectation too.

Comment: just follow the link.